# JasperReport : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException

Tags: java

Out line:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException
```

I using

Netbeans 7.2 + iReport plugin for Netbeans 7.2(iReport4.7.1)
Working with the plugin works in netbeans but when running the problem
libraries:

- jasperreports-4.7.1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
- commons-codec-1.6.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.7.jar
- commons-logging 1.1.jar
- jasperreports-4.7.1.jar

code:

```
try{
                String rutaReport = "src\\PckReports\\rBoleta.jasper";
                Map param = new HashMap();
                param.put("numComprobante",txtCorrelativo.getText());
                param.put("numSerie",txtSerie.getText());
                param.put("tipoComprobante", bol);
                param.put("numLetra",letra);
                JasperReport lReporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(rutaReport);
                //JasperReport lReporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("PckReports\\rBoleta.jrxml");
                JasperPrint jasp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(lReporte, param, this.jcn.Con());
                //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasp, "D:\\InformePaisesMySQL.pdf");
                JasperViewer ventana = new JasperViewer(jasp,false); 
                ventana.setTitle("Boleta de Venta -"+fechaEmisionBol());
                ventana.setVisible(true);
            }catch(HeadlessException | JRException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                System.out.println(""+ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you are trying to compile a Jasper binary file (rBoleta.jasper) as a Jasper (XML) source.

Try

```
 String rutaReport = "src\\PckReports\\rBoleta.jrxml";
 JasperReport lReporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(rutaReport);
```